# Remove bad characters from address

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I'm starting from a while to study the beautiful art of shellcoding. I'm remove all bad characters from my shellcode but I have some difficult to remove them from an address assigned to a register. I have this code that simply call `sys_read` and then `sys_write`:

```
section .data

welcome db 'Insert password: ', 0xA
welcomeLen  dq $-welcome
section .bss
input resb 4

section .text
_start:
mov al, 1
mov dil, 1
mov esi, welcome
mov edx, [welcomeLen]
syscall

; read password
xor al, al
xor dil, dil
mov esi, input
mov dl, 4
syscall
```

I ran objdump and this is the output:

```
  401072:       b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
  401074:       40 b7 01                mov    dil,0x1
  401077:       be 00 20 40 00          mov    esi,0x402000
  40107c:       8b 14 25 18 20 40 00    mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0x402018
  401083:       0f 05                   syscall 
  401085:       30 c0                   xor    al,al
  401087:       40 30 ff                xor    dil,dil
  40108a:       be 5c 20 40 00          mov    esi,0x40205c
  40108f:       b2 04                   mov    dl,0x4
  401091:       0f 05                   syscall
```

As you can see the only bad characters that I have are in these lines:

```
mov esi, welcome
mov edx, [welcomeLen]
mov esi, input
```

Can you explain how can I remove `00` from there?

Comment: What do you mean by “bad characters”? Why are you trying to remove 0s? These are part of the encodings for those instructions.

Comment: When you write a shellcode, you need to remove all bad charcters 0x0, 0xa, 0xd... In my case, 0x0 could be interpreted as the null terminator.

Comment: You'll have to find alternatives for the `MOV` instructions that are encoded differently. Be creative; that's sort of the point, I guess. Consider `PUSH` and `POP`. Also, do consider [edit]ing your question to clarify what you clarified to me in the last comment.

Comment: You will have to put your code and data in the same segment, you need to use RIP relative addressing and you need to place the data before it is referenced so the relative addressing works with negative displacement and you need to make sure the upper bits of the registers are zero when necessary. Something like this: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/test54544347.asm . You should also be able to assemble and link it to a runnable executable with: `nasm -felf64  test54544347.asm -o test54544347.o`  `gcc -nostartfiles test54544347.o -o test54544347 -N -static`

Comment: `welcomeLen  dq $-welcome` shouldn't be a memory location with the value of the length, you should use `EQU` to make it an assemble time constant.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try it out tonight!

Comment: It is probably a good idea to get a good understanding of regular assembly programming before trying to write shell code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch your code goes in Segmentation Fault. I need to understand better RIP relative addressing.

Comment: @DarkSkull Your code goes into a segmentation fault. I only provided code to do exactly what you were already doing. Your code would segmentation fault after getting input because after your code executes it starts to read instructions after the last syscall and whatever is in memory (all zeroes) faults your program. If you don't want it to seg fault you are going to have to do something else. You could use the exit syscall to exit. As well I hope you linked with the `-N` option as well.